# Does SchedularFactory returns same instance with new method

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using quartz schedular. In method 1 I am initializing my schedular like this

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.scheduleJob(someJob,someTrigger);
```

In method 2 if I do

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
```

Does the above call to the schedular factory will return the same instance that I have created in method 1 or will it return another instance and then I need to link all my jobs and trigger with that.

Comment: I wonder how is it easier to ask then to see/test yourself?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating 2 factories, they won't return the same scheduler. You should use a single factory if you want to use the same scheduler.

If you're using a single `StdSchedulerFactory`, the scheduler (if it exists) will be reused if it's not shut down:

```
public Scheduler getScheduler() throws SchedulerException {
    if (cfg == null) {
        initialize();
    }

    SchedulerRepository schedRep = SchedulerRepository.getInstance();

    Scheduler sched = schedRep.lookup(getSchedulerName());

    if (sched != null) {
        if (sched.isShutdown()) {
            schedRep.remove(getSchedulerName());
        } else {
            return sched;
        }
    }

    sched = instantiate();

    return sched;
}
```